# XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo("somepath")) is not configuring config file

Tags: c#, logging, web-config, log4net

I guess this question has been asked million times over the internet, but sadly none of the solutions works for me.

I'm writing a web api service and the architecture in my .net project us such that I have different layers like data access, service layer, javascript web client(which is apparently set as startup project) etc.

And I'm using an external xml config file named `MyConfigFile.config` (for logging) and I have  included this config file  in the root of javascript web client project and I also have added  the config file in appsetting of my root `web.confilg` file as mentioned below.

```
<appSettings>
      <add key="NSLog" value="~\MyConfigFile.config"/>
</appSettings>
```

I also added this line

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "MyConfigFile.config", Watch = true)]
```

to `AssemblyInfo.cs` and `MyConfigFile.config` file's build action is content and copy to output directory is copy always

I want to log error and info in controllers classes which are present in service layer, I have also added the content of entire xml config file in app.config file (which is one of the files in service layer project). But I haven't added anything to `AssemblyInfo.cs` in service layer(the way I did it for `AssemlyInfo.cs` to web client project mentioned above).
And then I'm using the following way to  configure external config file in each controller class

```
ICollection ic = XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileIinfo("path to external config file"));
```

In order to give path to FileInfo constructor I used million ways like

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyConfigFile"].ToString()
```

since I have this file mentioned in appsettings of my `web.config` file

then I used

```
 string path = Server.MapPath("~/MyConfilg.config");
```

then I used

```
string path = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + "MyConfigFile";
```

none of these throws a null but "ic" object of `ICollection` interface always return `count` as `zero`. And when I do the same in a console application by including my config file in a console application and then use the `Configure()` method with full physical path of external config file for `FileInfo` constructor parameter the object "ic" gives me count 4.

Why is "ic" giving me some count in console application why not in controller class of a web service.How should I go about giving a path value to FileInfo's constructor parameter so that "ic" object should start giving me some count value.

Comment: What do you mean, "throws a null"? Do you mean a `NullReferenceException`? On what line?

Comment: Ya I mean object reference set to null or something, but null is not the issue as you would have read it.

Comment: Sorry, thought you said "one of these throws a null".

Comment: I used string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSetting["MyConfig"].ToString() and then I did like path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(path); if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path) && File.Exists(path)){ ICollection ic = XMLConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo(path));}.... My code is going inside if statement and hitting that single line inside of it, that means my file does exists and path is not null or empty but then why ic gives me a 0 count for ICollection.

Comment: Fixed it on my own.Thanks

Comment: If you answer your own question, you can get rep for it. You can even accept the answer.

Comment: The answer is that i never got "ic" to gimme a count though logger is writing the logs for me and the plain answer to that is to get all the relative path for config as well as text log files.

Comment: And then convert these relative paths to absolute paths. Using System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("here a relative path whether its your config file or .txt file where log will be written to").